# filter keys by names contains string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, include

I'd like to filter in myArray keys by names contains string "item" (all "item1", "item2", "item3", etc)

```
const combined = myArray.map(e => Object.assign(e, MyArrayDefinition.find(k => k.item === e.item)));
```

I've tried this with .includes but it doesn't works

```
const combined = myArray.map(e => Object.assign(e, MyArrayDefinition.find(k => k.includes('item') === e.item)));
```

My arrays

```
const myArray = [{
            "shop": "shop1",
            "item1": "my apple 1",
            "item2": "my carrot 1",

        },  {
            "shop": "shop2",
            "item1": "my apple 0",
            "item2": "my carrot 1",

        }, {
            "shop": "shop2",
            "item1": "my apple 1",
            "item2": "my carrot 0",

        }, ];

        const MyArrayDefinition = [ {
            "item": "my apple 0",
            "color": "red",
            "group": "my fruit",
            "score": 0
        }, {
            "item": "my carrot 1",
            "color": "orange",
            "group": "my vegetable",
            "score": 1
        }, {
            "item": "my apple 1",
            "color": "red",
            "group": "my fruit",
            "score": 1
        }, {
            "item": "my carrot 0",
            "color": "orange",
            "group": "my vegetable",
            "score": 0
        }];
```

Comment: please add the wanted result ...

Comment: Are you comparing `item1` with `item` or `item2` with `item`?

Comment: what happens to `item2`?

Comment: I compare item1 and item2 with item to get their colors and their groups

Comment: please add the result to the question and add why item is the one and not the other item.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
const filtered = myArray.map((obj) => {
    const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    const result = objKeys.reduce((acc, k) => {
        if (k.match(/item/)) { // just keys withe "item"
            acc[k] = obj[k];
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});

    return result;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If an array of all found items is wanted, then you could filter the keys and get the items of the definition array.

```js
var array = [{ shop: "shop1", item1: "my apple 1", item2: "my carrot 1" }, { shop: "shop2", item1: "my apple 0", item2: "my carrot 1" }, { shop: "shop2", item1: "my apple 0", item2: "my carrot 0" }],
    definition = [{ item: "my apple 0", color: "red", group: "my fruit", score: 0 }, { item: "my carrot 1", color: "orange", group: "my vegetable", score: 1 }, { item: "my apple 1", color: "red", group: "my fruit", score: 1 }, { item: "my carrot 0", color: "orange", group: "my vegetable", score: 0 }],
    result = array.map(o => ({
        shop: o.shop,
        items: Object
            .keys(o)
            .filter(k => k.startsWith('item'))
            .map(k => definition.find(({ item }) => item === o[k]))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks your very much for your help ! but it's a multidimensionnal object. I need simple array with objects. Something like this  [{ shop:"shop1", "item": "my apple 1", "color": "red", "group": "my fruit", "score": 1},{ shop:"shop1", "item": "my apple 1", "color": "red", "group": "my fruit", "score": 1},etc]

Comment: which item do you want to take? `item1` or `item2`?

Comment: I would like to take all items

Comment: and how should look the array for the first object?

Comment: each object is an unique item+unique shop, and score is the sum of  them

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `filter` and function `includes` to filter those objects with keys === item and exist with the array `MyArrayDefinition`.

This example has the following object which values don't exist within `MyArrayDefinition`:

```
{  
    "shop": "shop33",
    "item1": "my apple 33",  
    "item2": "my carrot 33"
}
```

```js
const myArray = [{  "shop": "shop1",  "item1": "my apple 1 my fruit",  "item2": "my carrot 1",}, {  "shop": "shop2",  "item1": "my apple 0",  "item2": "my carrot 1",}, {  "shop": "shop2",  "item1": "my apple 0",  "item2": "my carrot 0",}, {  "shop": "shop33",  "item1": "my apple 33",  "item2": "my carrot 33",}],
      MyArrayDefinition = [{  "item": "my apple 0",  "color": "red",  "group": "my fruit",  "score": 0}, {  "item": "my carrot 1",  "color": "orange",  "group": "my vegetable",  "score": 1}, {  "item": "my apple 1",  "color": "red",  "group": "my fruit",  "score": 1}, {  "item": "my carrot 0",  "color": "orange",  "group": "my vegetable",  "score": 0}],
      mappedItems = MyArrayDefinition.map(({item}) => item), // convert to an array with only values from item.
      result = myArray.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => k.includes('item') && mappedItems.includes(o[k]))); // get the object with at least one key === item and which value exists within mappedItems.

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```